# Swift 2 save dateValue in first VC and load in secondVC

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have problems sending saved Data from a first VC to a second VC so it shows it on `viewDidLoad()`.
It does everything but it doesn't show me the date if I restart the app.

For example first VC:

```
@IBAction func btnEg(sender: AnyObject) {
    string = label.text;
    date = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(),
               dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle,
               timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle);

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let statistikvc: StatistikViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! StatistikViewController

        if (self.Count > 0) {
            statistikvc.date = date
            statistikvc.save(self.date)
        }
    }
```

Second ViewController:

```
var date = String();

func save(a: AnyObject?){
    defaults.setObject(a,forKey:"date")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let _ = defaults.objectForKey("date") as? String {
        self.txtDate.text = defaults.objectForKey("date") as? String
    }
    txtDate.text = date;
}
```

Comment: *"from first VC to the Second VC*" and *"show me the date if i restart the app"* are two completely different problems / tasks / situations. What is the exact problem here?

Comment: so the app shows me the Date in the second Vc .. that is good but the problem is that if i restart the app.. the value of date is gone

Comment: so the problem has nothing to do with passing data along but storing data across app launches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the call to [`defaults.synchronize()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) in your `save` function. Without it the data is not actually stored.

It should be:

```
func save(a: AnyObject?){
    defaults.setObject(a,forKey:"date")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

And you probably have to switch the two statements in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
txtDate.text = date;
if let _ = defaults.objectForKey("date") as? String {
    self.txtDate.text = defaults.objectForKey("date") as? String
}
```

Note that this will get messy. You are mixing two different mechanics here. You should **either always** use the handed over `date` or **always** use the default stored.

Comment: @Korken55 perfect! Please note the last two sentences I wrote: you should get clear how exactly you want to share data, you are currently mixing two techniques.

Comment: what do you mean with two techniques?

Comment: @Korken55 the userDefaults and passing the date through prepareForSegue. of what use the passed data if you simply store it and retrieve if from the defaults. You could easily store it in the firstVc and let the secondVc only read it. Or let the firstVc actually make all the reading and writing and always passing the correct value to secondVc.

Comment: oh ok that sounds really nice :) you have any suggestion or tags i should look for ?